# Tikz aligning text in nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I am working on a Tikz picture of a calendar.
The headings of the calendar are the months and I add them with nodes.
But they aren't aligned.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.3]
\path (0,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{sep}
  (1,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{oct}
  (2,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{nov}
  (3,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{dec}
  (4,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{jan}
  (5,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{feb}
  (6,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{mar}
  (7,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{apr}
  (8,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{mei};
\foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,...,8.5}
  \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,-5);
  \draw [fill = green] (-0.5,-1)rectangle node{Studie}(1.5,-1.5);
  \draw [fill = green] (1.5,-1.7)rectangle node{Structuur}(3.5,-2.2);
  \draw [fill = green] (3.5,-2.4) rectangle node{Dimensionering}(6,-2.9);
  \draw [fill = green] (6,-3.1) rectangle node {Interface} (8,-3.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I force the text to be on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the paragraph *Positioning Nodes Using Anchors* `[anchor=base]` is a possibility. I compact your code a little

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.3]

 \foreach \m [count=\mi from 0] in {sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar,apr,mei}
 \path[anchor=base] (\mi,0) node {\m} ;

\foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,...,8.5}  \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,-5);

      \draw [fill = green]
        (-0.5,-1)   rectangle node {Studie}         (1.5,-1.5)
        (1.5,-1.7)  rectangle node {Structuur}      (3.5,-2.2)
        (3.5,-2.4)  rectangle node {Dimensionering} (6,-2.9)
        (6,-3.1)    rectangle node {Interface}      (8,-3.6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the `base` anchor for these nodes, then the text is aligned on its baseline:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.3]
\path[anchor=base] (0,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{sep}
  (1,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{oct}
  (2,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{nov}
  (3,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{dec}
  (4,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{jan}
  (5,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{feb}
  (6,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{mar}
  (7,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{apr}
  (8,0)node[minimum height = 1cm]{mei};
\foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,...,8.5}
  \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,-5);
  \draw [fill = green] (-0.5,-1)rectangle node{Studie}(1.5,-1.5);
  \draw [fill = green] (1.5,-1.7)rectangle node{Structuur}(3.5,-2.2);
  \draw [fill = green] (3.5,-2.4) rectangle node{Dimensionering}(6,-2.9);
  \draw [fill = green] (6,-3.1) rectangle node {Interface} (8,-3.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```